# tinyMCE 6 image upload failing with no src

Tags: php, file-upload, tinymce

I've been struggling with the tinyMCE 6 image uploads for a week now and gone down every rabbit hole I can find on stackoverflow and in the docs.  Here is where I was yesterday:

I seem to be close but not quite there.  The issue I'm having is that the image uploads with the blobxxx.jpg name (and this is the name returned by my php handler), but then my editor saves the post with that image having no src.  It has the correct filename (but this doesn't match the blobxxx filename that was uploaded!)

Somehow, today the images aren't even uploading and I don't know what I changed. The images_upload_url doesn't even seem to be being called?  I didn't think I changed anything!  I've tried it without the image_title, but that has the same behavior just without a title.  I've tried with automatic_uploads:true, but that logs a GET error with the wrong file path (the file path of my images_upload_url php code)

I've been trying to use the examples from these docs: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/, https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my init:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: "#mytextarea",
   plugins: ["link","image"],
   toolbar: "undo redo | image | blocks | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent",
   tinycomments_mode: "embedded",
     /* enable title field in the Image dialog*/
  image_title: true,
  /* enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs*/
  automatic_uploads: false,
  images_upload_url: "<?php echo site_url("manage/project/tinyMCE_upload");?>",
  file_picker_types: 'image',
  file_picker_callback: (cb, value, meta) => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        /*
          Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
          registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
          necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        */
        const id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        const blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        const blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    input.click();
  },
   relative_urls : false,
   remove_script_host : false
});
```

the php code:

```
public function tinyMCE_upload() {    

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
  }

  // Don't attempt to process the upload on an OPTIONS request
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    return;
  }

  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);
    // Determine the base URL
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
    $baseurl = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/") . "/";

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
  }
 }
```

Comment: $filetowrite = $temp['name'];
Try by giving some path which have write permission 
$filetowrite = 'uploads/hello.jpg'

Comment: @Shibon the files did upload, that's the part that worked!  So I don't think it's an issue with the path? But they have the file names blobxxx.jpg and then there is no image src in the tinyMCE editor

Comment: images_upload_url: "<?php echo site_url("manage/project/tinyMCE_upload");?>",
change this path to the folder which file has uploaded